# Can i edit a my.cnf file on my server without using vi

Tags: ssh, putty, whm

How can i edit a my.cnf file on my server without using the highly confusing vi commands..?

I use WHM

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some other text editor. If `vi` is confusing, maybe you're lucky enough to have `mcedit` installed.

You can also copy the file on your machine with `scp`, edit it locally with your favorite editor and copy it back. [My confusing editor of choice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) does this kind of thing transparently, as if I was working with a local file.

Comment: emacs looks like it for people with an iq of over 180...mines hovering around 90 so i need a simpler solution...